# Twitter api "twit" fetching top trends but unable to use it

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, object, twitter

First of all, I appreciate your help.

when I tried to get top trends in particular region.
for the following code:-

```
var Twit = require('twit');
var config = require('./config');
var T = new Twit(config);
var params = {
    id: '1'
    // count: 3
}
T.get('trends/place', params, gotData);

    function gotData(err, data, response) {
        var tweets = data;
        console.log(tweets);
    }
```

I was expecting data something like [this (click and go to Example Response)](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/trends/trends-for-location/api-reference/get-trends-place)

but I got a response like this

```
C:\Users\Yash\IdeaProjects\yash>node bot3.js
[ { trends:
     [ [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object] ],
    as_of: '2018-01-25T14:59:11Z',
    created_at: '2018-01-25T14:54:58Z',
    locations: [ [Object] ] } ]
```

I would really appreciate if someone can help me to solve this issue.
I am very new to node.js. this is for a college project but I am stuck on this.

Comment: try `JSON.parse(data)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to convert the JSON objects returned into a string for display, so you can use (for example) `console.log(JSON.stringify(tweets, undefined, 2));`. The second and third parameters to stringify cause the output to be formatted in a more readable fashion for you.

Comment: you are beautiful. thanks a lot. the results came just as expected

Comment: feel free to mark this as the solution! you're welcome!

Comment: please 1 more thing if i want to display only name of json file i did this
function gotData(err, data, response) {
    var tweets = JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2);
   console.log(tweets)
    var tweet2 = tweets.trends
   for (var i = 0; i< tweet2.length;i++) {
       console.log(tweet2[i].name);
       console.log("\n");
    }
}
but it did not help
please help me